# When creating a function in the script tag, what object is it attached to as a member of?

Tags: javascript, html

When I create a function in the script tag just inside a HTML page, what object is it attached to?

```
<script>

var setTopOffset = function(row, rowHeight, pageSize) {
    listControl.moveListToWith(row,rowHeight,pageSize);
};

</script>
```

If I do console.log(window); I don't see where setTopOffset is, should it be there?

Comment: especially when we see that without `var` it does exist in the `window`

Comment: It **is** there. I see it in both Firebug and Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Whoa, [hey there](http://jsfiddle.net/PLHRW/).

Answer (score 2):

It is still attached to `window` object. Just do

```
console.log(window.setTopOffset);
```

Oh and you do see it in the list of `window` properties, just scroll it toward the bottom, below `sessionStorage`

Comment: @Cherniv you have to select "no wrap in body" in Fiddle option on the left. Check Brad's example: http://jsfiddle.net/PLHRW/

Answer (score 0):

it is attached to window but you need to add the window. before the variable 
please try this:

```
console.log(window.setTopOffset);
```

and you will see the function